# Android usb serial to web server app wrapper stops working

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to make a simple web server app for the Android which takes the query string from the URL, transmits to a serial device via a USB-serial cable, and returns the received response as text/plain.  The web server is implemented as a class which extends Thread and it and the USB-serial code been working fine for a while. (I think a separate thread is required for the TCP/IP network operations.)

I want the server to start when the USB-serial cable is attached and stop when the cable is unplugged. By doing this, I can make use of the "Launch this app every time the device is connected" so I don't have ask the user for USB permission every time.  There's no UI, so initially I thought I could make a service-only app, but I found that Android assumes that it is launching an app with a Main Activity.  I do have it starting OK when the cable is connected. I think I can ultimately make an empty main activity with a translucent screen and just call finish after starting the service.  And I've got a broadcast receiver which seems to be catching the USB disconnected event OK.

What I'm struggling with is that Android often says unfortunately your app has stopped working and wants to close it (kiil the process).  It does seem to hang up the UI, not sure how, since I've called finish.  The web server thread continues to work fine even while the "your app has stopped working" message is up, and it continues wo work fine until I answer yes which kills the process.

Is there anything special I have to do in the service, since my desire is to keep the service running after empty main activity finishes?  Am I on the right track?  Does the service need to run in its own process?

Thanks in advance for any insights you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

The service doesn't need to be in it's own process but it does need to be running on its own Thread.

Ensure that you web server extends the "Service" class and spawn a thread to do the work. In the onStartCommand do something like

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            // do web server stuff
         }
    };
    t.start();
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Then ensure no long running work is done in your broadcast receivers or activity classes.